# Can´t download images with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I can't download images. I have several problems (I tried so many variations). This is my code (I guess it has many errors)

The goal is to crawl the start URL and save all the product images and change its names by SKU number. Also, the spider has to click "next button" to do the same task in all the pages (there are around 24.000 products)

The problems that I noticed are:

1. I don't know the exact configuration with Items Pipelines
2. The images don't download on the folder in settings.py
3. I want to filter images by resolution and use thumbnails. Which one is the recommended configuration?
4. The images are located on another server. This is a problem?

`SETTINGS.PY`

```
BOT_NAME = 'soarimages'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['soarimages.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'soarimages.spiders'
DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'soarimages.items'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'soarimages.pipelines.soarimagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = '/soarimages/images'
```

`ITEMS.PY`

```
import scrapy

class soarimagesItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

`PIPELINES.PY`

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline

class soarimagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

def set_filename(self, response):
    #add a regex here to check the title is valid for a filename.
    return 'full/{0}.jpg'.format(response.meta['title'][0])

def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for image_url in item['image_urls']:
        yield scrapy.Request(image_url, meta={'title': item['title']})

def get_images(self, response, request, info):
    for key, image, buf in super(soarimagesPipeline, self).get_images(response, request, info):
        key = self.set_filename(response)
    yield key, image, buf
```

`Productphotos.PY` (Spider)

```
# import the necessary packages
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from soarimages.items import soarimagesItem

class soarimagesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'productphotos'
allowed_domains = ['http://sodimac.com.ar','http://sodimacar.scene7.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.sodimac.com.ar/sodimac-ar/search/']
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['http://sodimacar.scene7.com/is/image//SodimacArgentina/.*']), 'parse')]

def parse(self, response):
    SECTION_SELECTOR = '.one-prod'
    for soarimages in response.css(SECTION_SELECTOR):
        image = soarimagesItem()
        image['title'] = response.xpath('.//p[@class="sku"]/text()').re_first(r'SKU:\s*(.*)').strip(),
        rel = response.xpath('//div/a/img/@data-original').extract_first()
        image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel[0]]
        yield image

    NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = 'a.next ::attr(href)'
    next_page = response.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(next_page),
            callback=self.parse
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is my code (I guess it has many errors)

In fact I could spot at least one error: `allowed_domains` should list only the domains. You must not include any `http://` prefix:

```
allowed_domains = ['sodimac.com.ar', 'sodimacar.scene7.com']
```

You maybe want to fix this and test your spider. If new questions arise create specific questions for each specific problem. This makes it easier to help you. See also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks so much @Frank. The problem is solved! I can´t store the images in my computer anyway! I specify the path "IMAGES_STORE = '/Users/NicolasParraga/Desktop/soarimages/soarimages/images'" but didn´t work. Any suggest to fix it?

Comment: You are overriding the ImagePipeline. While this is great for implementing extra functionality it makes it harder to debug things. So maybe you want to start with a standard ImagePipeline and watch for any log messages indicating any problems. If you don't understand the log messages post a new question including code and log.